# Limit of n * ln(1+x/n)

Tags: exponential-function

How can you compute with the most primitive tools that:

> $$
> \lim_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}n \:\ln 
> (1+\frac{x}{n})=x
> $$

Using l'hospital verifies this. However we hadn't proofed l'hospital at this point.

---

The whole proof for context:

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $e^x=\lim \limits_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}$.

Without restriction $x \not= 0$. Let $x_n:= 1+\frac{x}{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x_n>0$ for $n >-x$ und $\lim\limits_{n
\rightarrow\infty}
x_n=1$. Hence
$$
1 \;{=}\; \ln'(1)=
\lim_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}\frac{\ln x_n-\ln 1}{x_n-1}=
\frac{1}{x} \lim_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}n\:
   \ln(1+\frac{x}{n}),
$$
then 
$$
\lim_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}n \:\ln 
(1+\frac{x}{n})=x
$$
hence 
$$
e^x=\lim_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}e^{n \:\ln 
(1+\frac{x}{n})}=\lim_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{n > -x}}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the limit definition of $e^x$

$$e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints for you to justify:

$$n\log\left(1+\frac xn\right)=\log\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\log e^x=x$$

Comment: the obstacle is that I need to show (1+x/n)^n = e^x